# React navigation drawer navigator with header back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using the drawer navigation from React Navigation v5. In my root file i've created the drawer navigator. Some of the screens inside of this navigator has a nested stack navigator. The first item is dashboard and the second item is Relations.

The problem is when I go to relations I don't get a back button for going to the first screen (Dashboard). Is it possible to add this to my relations screen?

Root code:

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <DrawerNavigator.Navigator
    drawerContent={(props) => (
      <SidebarComponent {...props} user={this.props.device.user} />
    )}
    drawerPosition="right"
    drawerStyle={{width: '90%', padding: 0, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    {this.props.authenticated && this.props.device.api_key ? (
      <>
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen
          name="Home"
          options={{
            headerShown: false,
            icon: 'tachometer-alt',
            category: 'dashboard',
          }}
          component={DashboardStack}
        />
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen
          name="Relations"
          options={{
            icon: 'address-book',
            category: 'dashboard',
          }}
          component={RelationsStack}
        />
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        <DrawerNavigator.Screen
          name="login"
          options={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}}
          component={LoginStack}
        />
      </>
    )}
  </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Relation stack code:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import RelationsListScreen from '../RelationsListScreen';
import {colors} from '../../../assets/styles/variables';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function RelationsStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerShown: true,
          headerTintColor: '#FFF',
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.primary,
            shadowColor: 'transparent',
          },
        }}
        name="Relations"
        component={RelationsListScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default RelationsStack;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a stack navigator that is a screen of your drawer navigator (when the user is authenticated) which has `Home` and `Relations` as screens. I've called this navigator `AuthenticatedNavigator` in the example below:

```
const AuthenticatedStack = createStackNavigator();
// ...

const AuthenticatedNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <AuthenticatedStack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <AuthenticatedStack.Screen
        name="Home"
        options={{
          icon: 'tachometer-alt',
          category: 'dashboard',
        }}
        component={DashboardStack}
      />
      <AuthenticatedStack.Screen
        name="Relations"
        options={{
          icon: 'address-book',
          category: 'dashboard',
        }}
        component={RelationsStack}
      />
    </AuthenticatedStack.Navigator>
  );
};

function CustomDrawerContent(props) {
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <DrawerItem
        label="Home"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Home')}
      />
      <DrawerItem
        label="Relations"
        onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate('Relations')}
      />
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
}

function App() {
  const authenticated = true;
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <DrawerNavigator.Navigator
        drawerPosition="right"
        drawerStyle={{width: '90%', padding: 0, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
        drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} />}>
        {authenticated ? (
          <DrawerNavigator.Screen
            name="authenticated"
            component={AuthenticatedNavigator}
          />
        ) : (
          <DrawerNavigator.Screen
            name="login"
            options={{headerShown: false, gestureEnabled: false}}
            component={LoginStack}
          />
        )}
      </DrawerNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

I've also used a custom drawer content component so the links in the drawer still work correctly after using the approach of creating another stack navigator. You can read more about providing a custom drawer component in the documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#providing-a-custom-drawercontent.

---

*I've left out some code and made `authenticated` a hardcoded value to simplify the example. Also be sure to import `DrawerItem`, `DrawerContentScrollView` from `@react-navigation/drawer`*.